# SqlExpress Installation Instance Name

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-express

I just wanted to know when installing SqlExpress 2008 when I choose mixed mode do I call the instance name .\SqlExpress or just SqlExpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance name should be `<server name>\sqlexpress`

a connection string would look like

```
Server=localhost\sqlexpress;Database=dbName;User ID=user;Password=pass;
```